# Looping LI elements in UL by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to code for looping by javascript and add < li > element to .It will be show lists of my information.

javascript code

```
 function querySuccess1(tx, results){
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
    var len = results.rows.length;

    if(!len)
    {
        alert("No!!!");
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    }else
    {
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
             document.getElementById("l1").innerHTML=results.rows.item(i).coompany;
      document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML=results.rows.item(i).fee ;

    }

        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();   
    }

}
```

HTML code

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="g" data-content-theme="a" data-inset="true" data-collapsed="false" >
        <h3><div id="r1"></div></h3>

    <ul data-role="listview" >
     <li style="padding-bottom:17px">   
     <span  id="l1"></span>
     <p class="ui-li-aside">
     <strong>
     <span  id="s1"></span>
     </strong>
     </p>
     </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

thank you very much

Comment: And what problem(s), *precisely*, did you want us to solve for you? Incidentally, any 'question' phrased as "I have JavaScript code and I want to you resolve my problems" (with or without the word 'please'), I expect to to see a request for our consulting fees.

Comment: "I want to you resolve my problems" should NEVER, EVER be said by anyone, to anyone, unless you're talking to Jesus.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I figured, but I was trying to help the OP not to offend everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

considering you're using jquery, you can use the each function... for example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Bye</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript using JQUERY**

```
$( "ul li" ).each( function() {

  alert( "This LI contains the text: " + $( this ).text() );

  if ( $( this ).text() == "Bye" )
  {
    alert( "I found you" );
  }

} );
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `$.each` function.

```
$('ul').children('li').each( function(){
  ... do stuff here
});
```

This will search through all the `ul` in the DOM.  I suggest you give the specific UL a class or id to limit the effort on the client side.